# bootstrap-vue v-tabs inside v-card renders 'undefined'

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Using bootstrap-vue I have a working example using b-tabs and some other of it's components.

However, on one page (.vue) when I try to wrap the  block within a  tag the page always renders that card and its contents as 'undefined'
I use the sample from [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs).

Without the v-card I see:

[image: no v-card]

and with it I see:

[image: with v-card]

The code literally follows the sample referenced in the page above and in my main.ts I have the following

```
import {Card} from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components'
import { Button } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';
import { Collapse } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';
import { Alert } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';
import { Tabs } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';

    Vue.use(Tabs);
Vue.use(Alert);
Vue.use(Collapse);
Vue.use(Button);
Vue.use(Card);

new Vue({
router,
store,
components: {
    bCard: Card,
    bButton: Button,
    bCollapse: Collapse,
    bAlert: Alert,
    bTabs: Tabs,
    pagination
},
render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction even to see how to isolate any underlying problem please?

EXTRA CODE ADDED BELOW

Vue (lang="ts") component which does not display correctly:

```js
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ml-1">
            <h4>Complaint Reference: {{ complaint.ComplaintReference }}</h4>
            <div class="col-12"><p>Enter the details of the complaint and click Save</p></div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <b-alert variant="success"
                         dismissible
                         :show="showDismissableAlert"
                         @dismissed="showDismissableAlert=false">
                    Your changes have been saved
                </b-alert>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- the next line is a separate vue component that uses the same approach and which renders correctly -->
            <tabs-view></tabs-view>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <b-card no-body> <!--   THIS IS WHAT BREAKS! -->
                    <b-tabs card>
                        <b-tab title="Details" active>
                            <p> in first tab</p>

                        </b-tab>
                        <b-tab title="Contact">
                            <p> in second tab</p>
                        </b-tab>
                        <b-tab title="Description">
                            <p> in third tab</p>
                        </b-tab>
                        <b-tab title="Outcome">
                            <p> in final tab</p>

                        </b-tab>
                    </b-tabs>
                </b-card>  <!--   THIS IS WHAT BREAKS! -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Prop, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";
    import {Complaint} from "@/components/complaints/Complaint";
    import TabsView from '../shared/Tabs.vue'
    @Component({
        components: {
            tabsView: TabsView
        }
    })
    export default class EditComplaintComponent extends Vue {
        complaint: Complaint = new Complaint("");
        baseUri: string = "api/Complaints/GetByReference/?id=";
        showDismissableAlert: Boolean = false;
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

and then another non-TS vue component consumed on the broken one which works correctly with b-tabs inside b-card

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <b-card title="Card Title"
                img-src="https://lorempixel.com/600/300/food/5/"
                img-alt="Image"
                img-top
                tag="article"
                style="max-width: 20rem;"
                class="mb-2">
            <!--<p class="card-text">-->
                <!--Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.-->
            <!--</p>-->
            <b-button href="#" variant="primary">Go somewhere</b-button>
            <b-card no-body>
                <b-tabs card>
                    <b-tab title="first" active>
                        <br>I'm the first fading tab
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab title="second" >
                        <br>I'm the second tab content
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab title="disabled" disabled>
                        <br>Disabled tab!
                    </b-tab>
                </b-tabs >
            </b-card>
        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    components: { }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue today, did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't actually fix this, I removed the tabs and card implementation because I was short on time.

Comment: I wasn't able to find this again but somewhere just after I had removed the b-card I discovered a post that related to data binding through b-card to lower controls. It didn't specifically relate to this problem but I seem to remember thinking the use of @Props ( I use TS component style of programming) in what I saw might actually have dealt with the problem

Comment: @barg and in case you run into this, I know there are issues with the vue-cli3 and TS debugging in both Rider/WebStorm and VS Code. But your discovery is consistent with what I was suspecting

Comment: Upgrade to the latest BootstrapVue to fix this issue.

Comment: I find it interesting that this issue, which I have found relates specifically to the use of `no-body` in `<b-card>`, still plagues me using BootstrapVue 2.20.1...

Comment: I'm having this issue anew with bootstrap-vue 2.21.2

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with bootstrap-vue 2.21.2.  Ended up being that I had a component that wasn't marked up with @Component.  After adding it in all my components went from 'undefined' text to display the proper content.  See https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5985#issuecomment-765558938.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of BootstrapVue to get around this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had a parent component missing the `@Component` decorator (in my case it was `App.vue`) that was causing the undefined behaviour. Make sure that all components have this decorator applied.